# Call to undefined function ssh2_connect() in php 8.1.1

Tags: php, ssh, xampp

Does anyone know where to find php_ssh2.dll download for php 8.1.1 or php 8.0.14
PECL downloads are not compatible

Comment: Which version of the PECL downloads have you tried? 1.3+ should be compatible with PHP 8, [according to the changelog](https://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=ssh2&release=1.3)

Comment: I develop on Windows but host on Linux, and whenever I need to ssh, SCP or SFTP, I always turn to [phpseclib](https://phpseclib.com/) which is cross platform and a little more obvious (IMHO) for configuring. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

Download the Thread Safe x64 - v 1.3.1 : https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/ssh2/1.3.1/php_ssh2-1.3.1-8.1-ts-vs16-x64.zip

or here :

http://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2/1.3.1/windows

unzip and copy and paste **php_ss2.dll** and **php_ssh2.pdb** to your extension directory : **php/ext**

Restart apache and it should works.